# Calculating ranges of different number types using POW

Tags: c

I am new here, like I am new in programming. I have read several threads but I cannot figure it out using parts from each.
I had homework to calculate how much bytes and bits every number type occupies, I did it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Broj bajtova za podatak tipa CHAR je %d, a broj bitova %d \n\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(char)*8);
    printf("Broj bajtova za podatak tipa SHORT je %d, a broj bitova %d \n\n", sizeof(short), sizeof(short)*8);
    printf("Broj bajtova za podatak tipa INT je %d, a broj bitova %d \n\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(int)*8);
    printf("Broj bajtova za podatak tipa LONG je %d, a broj bitova %d \n\n", sizeof(long), sizeof(long)*8);
    printf("Broj bajtova za podatak tipa FLOAT je %d, a broj bitova %d \n\n", sizeof(float), sizeof(float)*8);
    printf("Broj bajtova za podatak tipa DOUBLE je %d, a broj bitova %d \n\n", sizeof(double), sizeof(double)*8);
        return 0;
        system("PAUSE");
}
```

But today I have homework to calculate ranges of different number types using POW. I really don't have idea of this concept so I need your help. Please keep on mind that I am new into learning C...

Comment: please clarify what you mean by pow? is it the C library pow function or something else?

Comment: @Slay29 Welcome to stack overflow! Note that any relevant code should be included in the question itself. You can fix it by clicking the `edit` button under the [tag:c] tag. To get the formatting right: paste the code, select the code, and then click the code format button `{}`.

Comment: Every one has problem with POW...o_O :P

Comment: That gets tricky because the integers can be `signed` or `unsigned`, and floating point values are ... well ... complicated. But for an unsigned 8-bit value, the minimum is 0, and the maximum is `2^8 - 1`, which can be written as `pow(2,8) - 1`.

Comment: Yes, I know. But my teacher ask us to do this (c/p):
Write program that calculate value range for this type of information: char, short, int, long, float, double.
Warning: You have to use pow function.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

    int main()
{
    printf("Opseg brojeva za podatak tipa CHAR je od %d do %d \n\n", (int)pow(-2,7), (int)pow(2,7) -1);
    printf("Opseg brojeva za podatak tipa SHORT je od %d do %d \n\n", (int)pow(-2,15), (int)pow(2,15) -1);
    printf("Opseg brojeva za podatak tipa INT je od %d do %d \n\n", (int)pow(-2,31), (int)pow(2,31));
    printf("Opseg brojeva za podatak tipa LONG je od %d do %d \n\n", (int)pow(-2,31), (int)pow(2,31));
    printf("Opseg brojeva za podatak tipa FLOAT je od 3.4x10^-38 do 3.4x10^38 \n\n");
    printf("Opseg brojeva za podatak tipa DOUBLE je od 1.7x10^-308 do 1.7x10^308 \n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Only thing I cannot do is to represent FLOAT and LONG using pow.
Thank you guys!